# Sim800L time not updating to network time

Tags: arduino, at-command, sim800

Im hoping someone could help me please. I am trying to retrieve time and date from the Sim800L and I am coming short. I have a Sim800L here and I am communicating with it successfully over the Arduino IDE. I have used the following AT commands as suggested online with the following results.

AT+CCLK?

+CCLK: "04/01/01,03:59:51+00"

OK

AT+CLTS=1

OK

AT&W

OK

AT+CLTS?

+CLTS: 1

OK

After restarting, the date and time however is not set to network time. The network is a national carrier and should be able to do this.

AT+CCLK?

+CCLK: "04/01/01,03:59:51+00"

OK

Any ideas? 
Thank you

Comment: Did you already try use [this lib](https://github.com/cristiansteib/Sim800l/blob/master/Sim800l.cpp)?

Comment: yes. I am moving away from that library given the nature of my project. But all functions I have tried using in that library work, except the RTC functions. Not sure if I am calling the function in the right way though. is this correct: Sim800l.RTCtime(); ?

Comment: I have done the following checks: Ive taken the Sim800L simcard and put it into a phone. Then used the phone to check that auto-update-time on my phone works and it does. So the simcard is fine. I have also put my phone simcard into the Sim800L module and also could not get the correct time on the Sim800L module.

Comment: Can it be that the module works fine except for getting time?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same trouble. in this page [embedded world](https://www.raviyp.com/embedded/244-gsm-network-time-synchronization-for-rtc-using-at-clts-command) i Found something that works for me. it is add the following instruction
`AT&W`

> Read current time (You can see that the time is not right):
>
> AT+CCLK?
>
> +CCLK: "04/01/01,00:14:12+22"
>
> OK
>
> Enable auto network time sync :
>
> AT+CLTS=1
>
> OK
>
> Check if value is set :
>
> AT+CLTS?
>
> +CLTS: 1
>
> OK
>
> Save the setting to permanent memory so that module enables sync on restart also  :
>
> AT&W
>
> OK
>
> Restart the module and check time  :
>
> AT+CCLK?
>
> +CCLK: "18/06/21,12:00:21+22"
>
> OK

and it is all.

Comment: Is AT&W should work with Sim800c to save bluetooth status on? `AT+BTPOWER=1`

Answer (score 0):

You do correct but

Base on "SIM800 Series_AT Command Manual_V1.09" Edited on 2015-08-03
in page 154 in "6.2.12 AT+CLTS Get Local Timestamp" section

"Support for this Command will be network dependent."

**Change your network provider**

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, "AT+CCLK?" usually works (the network sets this time) IF using a network-branded-SIM (eg. EE or O2 branded).  However for **SOME** MVNO-SIMs (Mobile Virtual Network Operators SIMS) "AT+CCLK?" does NOT work (even where the same network-branded-SIM does).

Under these cases (for my SIM800L), if you need a valid time (for example so you can send a GPRS-email with a valid time-stamp), you have to manually set the time using: AT+CCLK="21/10/15,18:55:00+04"